# How to upload a file in a folder from django admin without using model

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file in a local directory called `uploads`. The directory structure is

```
Folder A
       Folder B
              Folder C
                     settings.py
                     urls.py
              <app_name1>
              Folder Static              
              manage.py
       uploads
```

`accounts/forms.py`--

```
class CouplingUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def validate_file_extension(value):
        import os
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]
        valid_extensions = ['.xml']
        if not ext.lower() in valid_extensions:
            raise ValidationError(u'Only files with ".xml" extension are supported, '
              'received: "%s" file.' % ext)

    coupling_file = forms.FileField(label='XML File Upload:', required=True, validators=[validate_file_extension])

    class Meta:
        model = models.Coupling
        exclude = ['coupling_name', 'module_name']
```

I don't have `model.FileField` so won't be able to use `upload_to`

`accounts/admin.py`

```
class couplingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('coupling_name','module_name')
    form = CouplingUploadForm
```

**Updated --**

I have created a view. There is no error but the file is not uploaded.

```
def uploadtest(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CouplingUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            print(newdoc)
            print("you in")
            newdoc.save()

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('static/uploads/test.xml', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

Is there any way so that I can upload a file in that `uploads` folder.

Any help/suggestion/link is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: rmember function def handle_uploaded_file(f): must be before from uploadtest

Comment: @MauricioCortazar Tried but same as before.